# Can someone tell me why this simple angularjs jsfiddle not working?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

Can someone tell me why this simple angularjs jsfiddle not working?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}]);
```

and

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    Hello, {{name}}!

</div>
```

results in

> Hello, {{name}}!

https://jsfiddle.net/cbdrow8u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `ng-app="myApp"` from the `div` tag.
2. Click the gear icon in the top right corner of HTML and in the BODY TAG field enter `<body ng-app="myApp">`.
3. Click the gear icon in the top right corner of JavaScript and in the LOAD TYPE select `No wrap - in <body>`
4. Click Update then Run.
5. Profit!

Comment: How do you know that? Where is the documentation?

Comment: I googled for `angularjs jsfiddle` and poked around a little.

Answer (score 4):

Click on JAVASCRIPT settings in the code panel and change LOAD TYPE from OnLoad to NoWrap in body.

Comment: How do you know that? Where is the documentation?